# How to write multiple lines of text in a box created using \framebox in LaTex

Tags: floats, formatting

I want to draw block diagram of a system. I used \framebox command to create blocks. But when I write long text inside the box it comes out of the boundaries of block. How can I write text in multiple lines? I used following code for making block diagram

```
\begin{figure*}[h]
\setlength{\unitlength}{0.14in} % selecting unit length
\centering % used for centering Figure
\begin{picture}(32,15) % picture environment with the size (dimensions)
% 32 length units wide, and 15 units high.
\put(3,4){\framebox(6,3){Symbol Mapping}}
\put(13,4){\framebox(6,3){$N[\cdot]$}}
\put(23,4){\framebox(6,3){$H_{C}(q)$}}
\put(0,5.5){\vector(1,0){3}}\put(9,5.5){\vector(1,0){4}}
\put(19,5.5){\vector(1,0){4}}\put(29,5.5){\vector(1,0){3}}
\put(-1,6.5) {$u(k)$}\put(30,6.5) {$y(k)$} \put(9.5,6.5)
{$x_{B}(k)$}\put(19.5,6.5) {$x_{C}(k)$}
\end{picture}
\caption{An LNL Block Oriented Model Structure} % title of the Figure
\label{fig:lnlblock} % label to refer figure in text
\end{figure*}
```

Comment: `\begin{figure*}[h]` you can not use `h` with `figure*` so this figure is not allowed anywhere and will go to the end of doument unless flushed with `\clearpage`

Comment: `\framebox(..){\parbox{5cm}{long text here....}}` will allow multi-line text